# ruby class to send email gives arguments problems

Tags: ruby, email

So i have wrote this very simple emailer utility in ruby, but when i run it it tells me that i'm passing an argument where i should not?

```
1  #!/usr/bin/ruby
     2  require 'mail'
     3
     4  class Mailer
     5
     6    #Sends emails without attachment
     7    def send(subject,recipients,body,from)
     8         Mail.defaults do
     9          delivery_method :smtp,{ :address => 'localhost', :port => 25,:openssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
    10         end
    11          mail = Mail.new do
    12           from "#{from}"
    13           to "#{recipient}"
    14           subject "#{subject}"
    15           body "#{body}"
    16          end
    17         mail.deliver!
    18    end
    19
    20  end
```

I run it like this:

```
   subject="something"
   recipients="me@mycompany.com"
   mailer=Mailer.new
   from="me@mycompany.com"
   body="this is the body"
   mailer=Mailer.new
   mailer.send(subject,recipients,body,from)
```

This raises:

```
.rb:221:in `send': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.15/lib/treetop/runtime/compiled_parser.rb:18:in `parse'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/elements/address_list.rb:26:in `initialize'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `new'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `parse'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:100:in `value='
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/structured_field.rb:29:in `initialize'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/from_field.rb:41:in `initialize'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:203:in `new'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:203:in `new_field'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:192:in `create_field'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:119:in `initialize'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:175:in `new'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:175:in `[]='
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:1184:in `default'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:637:in `from'

/Mailer.rb:12:in `block in send'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:132:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:132:in `initialize'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:50:in `new'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:50:in `new'
```

Any idea whats wrong in my code?

Comment: [`send` is a built-in method of `Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send), you probably don't want to use this name (this could be your problem, didn't test).

Comment: let me give it a try, thx